# Tag-it variable cannot pass as post variable in html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, tags, tag-it

I Use below html page for tag-it. But when i submit the form, i can't get the value from form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://girlzunderground.com/code/tagit.js"></script>  
<script >
$(function() {
    $('#demo3').tagit({
        tagSource:function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/test.com/tag/tagdb.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        triggerKeys:['enter', 'comma', 'tab'],
        allowNewTags: false
    });
});

//http://girlzunderground.com/php/profile-tags.php?t=books&txt=book
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
<form action="display.php" method="post">
        <ul id="demo3" class="tagit">
        <li class="tagit-new" >
                 <input id="test1" name="test1[]" style="width:200px;" class="tagit-input ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"/>
                </li>
        </ul>
       <input type="text" value="qqq" name="q"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i submit the form, i can't get input "test1" value. But i can get input "q" value.

This is my display.php page

```
<?php
$Category=$_POST['test1'];
$q=$_POST['q'];
echo $q;
//exit();
$allCourse=NULL;
$count=0;
foreach($Category as $Cat)
{
 $count=$count+1;
 $allCourse=$allCourse.'~'.$Cat;
}
$allCourse=$allCourse.'~';
echo $allCourse;
?>
```

How can i get my tag-it value from html form..

Comment: You are only passing `q` -> `data: {q: request.term}`. Have you tried adding it to the passed data -> `data: {q: request.term, test1: $('#test1').val()}`?

Comment: I tried.. But not working

Comment: @Sean example seems to work in this environment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gehdpen/ - when you say it's not working, what are you getting? A blank value?

Comment: @Sean Blank value. When i sumbit, the display.php page says
Notice: Undefined index: test1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\doobigo.com\tag\display.php on line 2

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\doobigo.com\tag\display.php on line 8